Is it possible to divide points to regions only based on their minimum distance to region-dividing curves?
I have a a set of scattered points with known coordinates on a plane (see schematic image), and four curves (C1-C4) that divide the whole plane into regions (R1-R5). I also know the minimum distance of each point to each curve. Is there a way to estimate which region the point falls into just based on this information? I would like to write code to do that in Python. My thinking is, to first find which minimum distance is the smallest for each point - that narrows down the options which region the point belongs to. But then how do I know which side of the curve the point falls on? For example, points A and B both have the smallest minimum distances d1 and d2 to curve C3, which would means they are either in region R3 or R4, but is there a way to narrow down which one? Curious to see if any solutions here are possible, or if more information is necessary to solve this problem. 
Edit:
Here is an example code. I simplified it a bit. The data is stored in dataframe:
columns = ['Point', 'x', 'y', 'd1','d2','R']
data = [("A",1.5, 3.5, 1.2, 2.8, "NA"), ("B",3.5, 2.5, 0.8, 0.7, "NA"), ("C", 3.0, 0.5, 2.1,0.5,"NA")]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

The region names are in a list:
regions=["R1","R2","R3"]

And output dataframe should be:
output_columns = ['Point', 'x', 'y', 'd1','d2','R']
output_data = [("A",1.5, 3.5, 1.2, 2.8, "R1"), ("B",3.5, 2.5, 0.8, 0.7, "R2"), ("C", 3.0, 0.5, 2.1,0.5,"R3")]
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_data, columns=output_columns)



Interesting problem! Could you add some code to show how the minumim distances between each curve and each point are stored? Otherwise, there are too many decisions involved for this to be a viable programming question for SO. An example of data and an expected result would also help.

Are the curves restricted in any way? For example, are they sections of concentric circles, possibly even with equal increments in radius? Or are these arbitrary curves, including "wiggly" ones (i.e. zig-zagging like a sinusoid curve)?

For what purpose are you trying to do this?

I don't think you can do it with the data provided, because the curve C4 (on the coloured diagram) could be really far away, making A very far from this C4, and closer to C2.
I think you need to generate a new point, the one on C3, closest to A, call this point D.

Then you can find distance of D->C4, compare it to A->C4 to determine the region of A.
More generally I think you need at least one additional distance from a point you create based on A.
Edit:
I'm certain it isn't possible because this

has identical distances to this

But different regions
